# Прошу подсказать как реализовать проверку Email в SQL

Tags: sql

**Создал таблицу SQL (данные ниже для нее), необходимо добавить SQL функцию** check_email( $email ) *- проверяет емейл на валидность и возвращает 0 или 1. Функция работает от 1 секунды до 1 минуты. Вызов функции платный.* **Прошу подсказать как реализовать такое. В учебниках не нашел. Не знаю как подступиться. Через переменную может?**

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  id INTEGER,
  username VARCHAR(50),
  validts TIMESTAMP with time zone,
  confirmed BIT,
  emails_id INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE emails (
  id INTEGER,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  checked BIT,
  valid BIT,
  users_id INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE emails ADD FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES Users (id);  

INSERT INTO Users (id, username, validts, confirmed, emails_id) VALUES (1, 'Ivanov', '2022-09-25 10:23:51+02', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO Users (id, username, validts, confirmed, emails_id) VALUES (2, 'Petrov', '2022-08-26 05:10:35+02', '0', '2');
INSERT INTO Users (id, username, validts, confirmed, emails_id) VALUES (3, 'Sidorov', '2022-09-27 15:27:24+02', '1', '3');

INSERT INTO emails(id, users_id, email, checked, valid) VALUES (1, 1, 'Ivanov@mail.ru', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO emails(id, users_id, email, checked, valid) VALUES (2, 2, 'Petrov@mail.ru', '0', '0');
INSERT INTO emails(id, users_id, email, checked, valid) VALUES (3, 3, 'Sidorov@mail.ru', '1', '0');
```

Comment: Сначала определите ВСЕ шаблоны адресов, которые считаются валидными. Например, `"Василий Пупкин"@mail.ru` - вполне себе валидный, полностью соответствующий RFC, адрес, но должна ли функция пропускать такой?

Comment: *Функция работает от 1 секунды до 1 минуты.* o_O что там делать не то что минуту - там даже на секунду работы не найти... *необходимо добавить SQL функцию check_email( $email ) - проверяет емейл на валидность и возвращает 0 или 1* Нафига? засунуть её прямо в таблицу (generated column) и не париться.

Comment: @Akina что-то мне кажется, что проверка - это проверить есть ли такой  адрес в базе или нет.

Comment: PS. https://habr.com/ru/post/224623/

Comment: @teran А в чём тут валидность? Это проверка на существование/присутствие/прочее. Внешнее. Тогда как валидность - чисто внутреннее свойство.

Comment: мда. хороший вопрос. мб тогда какой нить шаблон нужен типа  `users.username + @*`. но чет СУБД явно не то место, где надо проводить валидацию адресов.

Comment: @teran Ну с таким подходом можно вообще всю подсистему контроля СУБД сливать в корзину и делать из базы тупое и бессловесное хранилище, а всю валидацию вести на клиенте (впрочем, практически все фреймворки в той или иной степени именно это и делают). Забивание гвоздей микроскопом. Валидация значения (пусть и по сложному шаблону) - это сравнительно простая задача.